# Help! Have I dreamed that?

Tags: gazebo-camera, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

Less than three months ago, I came to know that there was a simulator feature that was really what I needed. A sensor plugin to simulate a "virtual camera" that tells you which object is currently seen. I absolutely can't remember where I read this stuff and in the list of available plugins (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) there's no such thing.

Can you please tell me if there's such a functionality in gazebo and how to find it?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17093/help!-have-i-dreamed-that?/) by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sounds like you're talking about the [logical camera](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=sensor#sensor_logical_camera). [Here is](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/1054201b80f7768d4f163a73df137a7ecc9e2e3e/worlds/logical_camera.world?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) a world that uses it. I don't see any tutorials for it, but if you figure it out a contribution of a tutorial would be very welcome [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/).

Looks like there is a message [logical_camera_image.proto](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/1054201b80f7768d4f163a73df137a7ecc9e2e3e/gazebo/msgs/logical_camera_image.proto?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).There may be a topic publishing that message. The [logical_camera_sensor integration test](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/1054201b80f7768d4f163a73df137a7ecc9e2e3e/test/integration/logical_camera_sensor.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) should show howto read the camera output.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2017-08-24**:
I've launched logical_camera.world, but how am I supposed to read the camera output?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-08-24**:
I updated the answer with a link to a message and the tests for the logical camera sensor. I haven't used this sensor myself, but if I needed to use it those links are where I would start.